# How to get error status code in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling

I am using ASP.NET MVC and the below code to return an exception description and store it in a session. I need help finding out the error code of the exception, like `500`, `403`, `404`, etc. How can I do that?

This is how I am storing the error message in a session:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["errorMessage"] = filterContext.Exception.Message.ToString();

public override void OnException(System.Web.Mvc.ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    ProcessResult processResult = new ProcessResult();

    // If the exception is already handled, we do nothing
    if (filterContext.ExceptionHandled)
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        var controllerName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        var actionName = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
        var model = new HandleErrorInfo(filterContext.Exception, controllerName, actionName);
        processResult.Controller = controllerName;
        processResult.Action = actionName;
        processResult.ExceptionMessage = filterContext.Exception.Message;
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["errorMessage"] = filterContext.Exception.Message.ToString();
        processResult.StackTrace = filterContext.Exception.StackTrace;
        processResult.Source = filterContext.Exception.Source;
    }
    // Mark the exception as handled
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check to see if the Exception is an HttpException. Then cast it as such and grab the status code.

```
if (filterContext.Exception is HttpException)
{
    var statusCode = ((HttpException)filterContext.Exception).GetHttpCode();
}
```